# Laravel stopped writing logs on Azure

Tags: php, laravel, azure, logging

Up until recently any error messages laravel would produce were written to /app/storage/logs on Azure, as they are supposed to. They still do locally, and my live server uses the exact same laravel-configuration. However, on my live server laravel stopped writing to the log files about 2 months ago.

Log::Info still works, but unless I tell it to write something to the logs it doesn't.

As it works locally and the exact same configuration is live, I don't know where I should start looking, and googling has revealed to be fruitless. I'm sorry I have not included any images or code, but I am completely clueless what could cause the error. Maybe it has something to do with writing privileges? Any ideas?

**Progress 1:** When something is supposed to be written to the logs-folder, the "Most recently modified at"-date changes to current date and time. However, nothing inside the folder changes.

**Progress 2:** An error was just printed to the log, but not all errors are printed. There is an imagick error that should be printed to the log that currently isn't, but the fact that another error message was printed changes the entire question. Just found out, going to test some stuff now.

**Progress 3:** I have confirmed that the only thing not printed to the log is when imagick fails to load a pdf. There are other cases of this particular problem of imagick happening on a windows server, where reading pdf:s causes imagick to crash without any error message. This means that this question is no longer relevant, thank you for all your time people.

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether the disk space is full of your App Service, if so, it may raise your issue.

And every App Service pricing tier has a limit disk space and will shared in all the web apps in this App Service plan.
You can check the metric on **dashboard** page of your web app portal, e.g.
[image]

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ for details.

As a workaround, you can build a web job to run a script continuously to move your old log files to Azure Blob Storage or a database, to save storage space in App Service.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked and I'm only using 8% of my disk space, so disk space is not the problem.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about what have you set on Azure Web Apps since you occurred the issue. As on my side, i cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied and that this response does not help, just letting you know I'm currently very sick. Excuse my short reply, my mind is hazy.

Comment: What you set **Log Modes** at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration ? if set as `syslog` and `errorlog`, it will not log error messages into the file in my test.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's set to 'log' => 'daily', just like I have it locally and it works locally.